# JavaScript Array to String

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm using the jQuery plugin jQuery-Tokenizing-Autocomplete in a rails application with a has_many association.

I need to save the values to the database, but to do that I need it to be a string, not an array. So the result should equal "1","2","3". Hope this clarifies.

The javascript used to generate this array:

```
$.TokenList.ParseValue = function (value, settings) {
  var result = [];
  $.each(value, function(i, node) {
    if (node) {
      result.push(node.id);
    }
  });
  return result;  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

for array to string in javascript you can do it like this.

```
var str = (['1', '2', '3']).join(","); // will result to 1,2,3
```

similar syntax works for ruby code

```
['1', '2', '3']).join(",") # will return 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

The default separator for `join` is the comma, so remove the `'","'` argument.  You are specifying a separator of `","` so the double quotes must be escaped in the result string, hence the backslashes.

Comment: That leaves me with "hotel_ids"=>["1,2,3"] and not the ["1","2","3"] that rails require.

Comment: Why not split the array into an array of separate strings back in the controller?  Something like hotel_ids[0].split(',')

Comment: $ irb
>> a = ["1,2,3"]
=> ["1,2,3"]
>> a[0].split(',')
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
>>

Comment: Great idea, would you happen to know the best way to make the array a string? the split method makes it an array. So the end result is [["1","2","3"]]. Thanks!

Comment: If you have an array or arrays, use the flatten method.

[["1","2","3"]].flatten yields ["1","2","3"]

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = '"' + array.join('","') + '"'; // "1","2","3"
```

Comment: That works, except for the it getting escaped: "1\",\"2\",\"3"